# pycharm venv run will not find modules

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

just started a new flask project.
This is all I got so far:

```
from flask import Flask

from config import *

site = Flask(__name__)

@site.route('/')
def home():
    return "<h1>Hello Nurse</h1>"

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
   site.run(port=4200)
```

This runs fine when I run from the terminal, because virtualenv is properly activated as shown by my prompt:

```
(hemp_timer) [NovasectorDT:~/home2/prog/raspberrypi/hemptimer] (master)
```

but when I try to run/debug it (shift+F10 or shift+F9), I get the following error:

```
/home/detrix42/home2/prog/raspberrypi/venv/hemp_timer/bin/python /home/detrix42/.local/shareJetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/203.6682.86/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 45061 --file /home/detrix42/home2/prog/raspberrypi/hemptimer/site.py
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/detrix42/home2/prog/raspberrypi/hemptimer/site.py", line 1, in <module>
     from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

flask is installed in virtualenv, and the virtualenv (venv) is in the path, and is the first one in the path.

What am I missing?

**Figured out what I was doing wrong** (edit)
I had named my flask app 'site.py' and that name is already taken by other python module. Changed the name to site_app and it works as expected. :face_palm:

Comment: Edit configuration near the "run/debug" button, Then select the python interpreter inside your venv. Possibly do it in setting, to set the default interpreter for the antire project

Comment: The python interpreter that is being used is in the venv. This is why I am confused.

Comment: PyCharm do not care the Python in PATH. You should specify in PyCharm which env you are using (and you can use different venv between projects, and also inside projects).